# facebook share a page with a photo

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook

When I click 'Share', then it opens facebook share page in a new tab. I want to show temp.jpg in left bar in this page. How to do this?

test.aspx

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<!-- AnythingSlider #1 -->
<ul id="slider1" style="width: 778px; height: 452px; background:#fff;">
    <li>
        <div style="float: left; padding-right: 35px; padding-left:50px;">
            <img src="../../img/temp.jpg" style="width: 264px;
                height: 377px; border: none;" />      
            <uc:DownloadControl ID="DownloadControl1" runat="server" PageParameters="1" />
        </div>                
    </li>
    <li>
    <uc:DownloadControl ID="DownloadControl2" runat="server" PageParameters="2" />
```

...

DownloadControl.ascx

```
<div style="float: left">
<a class="icerik" id="facebookShare" runat="server" target="_blank">
<img border="0" src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="Resorts"
    title="Hotels & Resortss" /> Share </a>
```

DownloadControl.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
 facebookShare.HRef = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.test.com/test.aspx";
 }
```

Comment: For new development, you should not be using `sharer.php`. It is deprecated and may stop working at any time. Use the [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom information about your page while sharing with *sharer.php*, you must place additional open graph meta tags in the head of your page. For this example, test.com/test.aspx contains these tags:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Test" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.test.com/test.aspx" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.test.com/img/temp.jpg" />
// other meta tags
</head>
```

More information about Open Graph protocol is [here](http://ogp.me/)